How to show Cyrillic letters in PDF
How to use Cyrillic characters in Jasper reports?
I see fonts in preview mode, but when generating in code - no.
I have already checked the built-in font box and connected the font.


Dependency:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-pdf</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

.jrxml file:
    <title height="56">
        <element kind="textField" uuid="99150c5f-a164-4b0f-a420-9a38b1ecc208" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="56" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="33.0" linkType="None" linkTarget="Self" hTextAlign="Center" vTextAlign="Middle">
            <expression><![CDATA["Привет мир"]]></expression>
        </element>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.grid.JSSGridBagLayout"/>
    </title>

Generated PDF:

